# How to convert html pages into erb in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been given the task to convert some static html pages into erb pages, to be used in a Rails project. Since all pages belong to same project, they are having a common "application.html.erb" file. But all Html pages have different class names for `<body>` tag. and since we have common "application.html.erb" file. How to convert such Html pages with different names for `<body>` tag , into .erb files?

Comment: Can you explain some more about what you mean by "have different class name for tag" please, in an edit to your question.

Comment: <html><body class="home-page"></body></htlml> - 1st page         <html><body class="about-page"></body></html>- 2nd page....                                                             this way all pages have different class name.                             And since "application.html.erb" file have common <body> tag, for all the pages, that belongs to same project. How do i handle such html pages with different class..

Comment: i have been given the hint of putting a Variable and if-else condition in "application.html.erb" file.. but i am not able to figure out any solution through this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with an instance variable, which is expected to be set in the controller.

```
<body class="<%= @body_class %>">
```

You can then set this on a per-controller or per-action basis.  If there is a "formula" to decide what it is, based on the controller and action, you could do it via a single before_filter defined in ApplicationController.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [curren_page?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) helper method that gives you understanding where you are.

Using this method you can create your own helper that adds class method to your body in application layout.